# Don't get any result when I click on my item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I'm using recyclerView in my apps, and when I click on the item, I get nothing. I've tried to print text to see if the click work but nothing. I've followed many tutorials but still not working. Can I know where the problem is?
  I need to implement this click.

Here is my code :

AdapterClass

```
public class DosAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<DosAdapter.DosHolder>{
private List<Dossier> dossiers = new ArrayList<>();
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DosAdapter.DosHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, 
int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.folder_item, parent, false);
    return new DosHolder(itemView,this.listener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DosAdapter.DosHolder holder, int 
position)
{
    Dossier currentDos = dossiers.get(position);
    holder.titre.setText(currentDos.getTitre());

}

public static class DosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private TextView titre;

    public DosHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        super(itemView);
        titre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_titre);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

Activity

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new 
   DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), 
   DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

     DosAdapter adapter = new DosAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new DosAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Aside from the answer that I posted, I can only guess from your code that if you change the object that performs the clickListener from itemView to titre, your code might still just work.

Answer (score 0):

> > **Do you mind using this? I make sure the naming match yours and you can just copy the whole code and paste without any errors to deal with, just make sure you read the few comments to understand not just use only.**

**FOR YOUR ADAPTER**

```
public class DosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private List<Dossier> dossiers = new ArrayList<>();

    public DosAdapter(OnItemClickListener listener, List<Dossier> dossiers) {
        this.dossiers = dossiers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.folder_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        try {
            final Dossier currentDos = dossiers.get(position);
            holder.titre.setText(currentDos.getTitre());

            holder.titre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage()+"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dossiers.size();
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                          GET REFERENCES TO VIEWS HERE
     *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView titre;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_titre);
        }
    }
}
```

**HOW TO USE THE ADAPTER FROM THE ACTIVITY THAT NEEDS IT.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private DosAdapter dosAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Dossier> dossiers = new ArrayList<>();
        //I'm assuming you already feed your data, so you're not passing null like me here.

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        dosAdapter = new DosAdapter(this, dossiers);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new
                DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dosAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        System.out.println("clicked position: "+position);

        /*
        * This will help your tracing from Logcat much easy to trace,
         * simply open Logcat and switch from verbose/Debug to Error,
         * like that you will not have much logs and tracking the
         * printout becomes easier.
         * */
        Log.e("CLICK TAG", "Clicked position"+position);
    }
}
```

If you take your time to go through it, you will understand it better.